# How to create a type that returns and object with classes excluded

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Given the following:

```js
class MyClass {}
class MyOtherClass { something!: number; }

type HasClasses = {
    foo: MyClass;
    bar: string;
    doo: MyClass;
    coo: {x: string;};
    boo: MyOtherClass;
};

type RemovedClasses = RemoveClassTypes<HasClasses>;
```

I want `RemovedClasses` to equal `{ bar: string; coo: {x: string;} }`. How can I do that?

I have tried what I thought would work but it didnt for some reason:

```js
type ClassesKeys<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends new () => any ? P : never;
}[keyof T]

type RemoveClassTypes<T> = Omit<T, ClassesKeys<T>>;
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing the question a bit based on the comments under my now-deleted answer. Apologies in advance if I've changed it in a way that you didn't mean, but I'm fairly sure and I think it's clearer to have a second class in the example.

Comment: Here's a question I should have thought to ask you yesterday: **Why** do you want to do this? This seems like [an X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): What is it you're trying to do that you need this `RemoveClassTypes` for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're saying you want to remove properties from the type based on whether they relate to classes, leaving non-`class` object types. That's why in your example you're removing `foo` and `doo` (both `MyClass`) and `boo` (`MyOtherClass`), but not `coo` (`{x: string;}`).

I don't think you can.

TypeScript's type system is *structural* (based on the shape of things), not *nominal* (based on their names). An object is just an object, it doesn't say whether it was created via `new X()` or `Object.create()` or an object literal — not at the type level, and largely not at the runtime JavaScript level either. What matters is the properties and methods that it has; its *shape*.

For example, look at this:

```typescript
class Example {
    something: string;
    constructor(s: string) {
        this.something = s;
    }
    method(): void {
    }
}

let ex1 = new Example("ex1");
let ex2 = {
    something: "ex2",
    method(): void {
    }
};
```

From the type perspective, there's no difference between `ex1` and `ex2`, even though at a runtime perspective there is a minor difference (`ex1` inherits its `method`, while `ex2` has it as an own property).

Now assume you have these declarations:

```typescript
let ex3: Example;
let ex4: { something: string; method(): void; };
```

**All** of these assignments are valid:

```typescript
ex3 = ex1;  // Works
ex3 = ex2;  // Works
ex4 = ex1;  // Works
ex4 = ex2;  // Works
ex1 = ex4;  // Works
ex2 = ex4;  // Works
```

The types of those things are all compatible. The instance type `Example` declared via a `class` construct, the type inferred from the object initializer for `ex2`, and the inline type assigned to `ex4`, they're all compatible with each other.

One red herring would be that objects from classes have an inherited `constructor` property, maybe we can use that! But you can't, because even `ex2` above has an inherited `constructor` property (from `Object.prototype.constructor`, which is `Object`), and separately I think TypeScript treats the `constructor` property a bit specially (but can't point to any docs on that and may be mistaken).

So I'm afraid I don't think you can do what you've said you want to do.